# What causes ferromagnetic marbles to jump away from a magnet when it's pulled to other marble?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation

Here is a video: https://youtu.be/QQ9gs-5lRKc?t=48

The construction, as far as I know, is nearly horizontal, just slightly tilted.

Here's a frame before collision:

> [image: Frame before collision]

And frame after collision:

> [image: Frame after collision]

And simple pictorials:

o - magnet marble (small)

O - ferromagnetic marble (large)

The way I see it, it behaves like this:

Before collision 1st marble moves with some velocity towards a magnet and two marbles:

O--> oOO

Then after collision, the marble that was moving stops and the last marble jumps off with velocity greater than the previously moving marble:

OoO O---->

I don't understand this speed boost. Where is it coming from? What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Seems to be moving like a [newton's cradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_cradle), then after, gets pulled by another magnet.

Comment: Throw in [Galilean cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_cannon) and you are ready to go.

Comment: I would really have to see the collisions in slow-motion to be sure about the sequence of events, but I think that friction does play a significant role in the dynamics. As for the question of where the energy to accelerate the marble comes from, that's easy to answer: It comes from the stored magnetic potential energy associated with all the paired permanent spherical magnets that it hits.